# Auditing (@CreatedDate) does not work for WebFlux Spring Boot with reactive MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive, audit, spring-data-r2dbc

Does WebFlux Spring Boot with reactive MongoDB supports Auditing?
I tried to use `@CreatedDate` and it did not work for me.
Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@EnableMongoAuditing
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReactiveMongoConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Here is my document class

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
...    
import java.util.Date;

@Document
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Message implements Persistable<String> {
  @Id private String id;

  private String text;

  @CreatedDate
  private Date createdDate;

  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    return createdDate == null;
  }
```

Here is Message repository

```
@Repository
public interface IMessageRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Message, String> {}
```

When I save message `messageRepository.save(message)` I always have `createdDate=null`

Do I miss something or Auditing does not work with reactive MongoDB?

Comment: Would you show `message` where `"createdDate"` is not what you want?

Comment: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("6288f14af6e75b720d77facd"), "text" : "Hello", "_class" : "com.mgtest.app.model.dao.Message" }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using `@EnableReactiveMongoAuditing`, not `@EnableMongoAuditing` as I initially did. Apparently the reactive annotation should be used with `ReactiveMongoRepositories`. So the correct configuration is the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@EnableReactiveMongoAuditing
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReactiveMongoConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {
...
}
```

So after saving a message the corresponding `createdDate` is added automatically:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("628a01d77f74d46c62a5bb36"), "text" : "Hello", "createdDate" : ISODate("2022-05-22T09:26:47.280Z"), "_class" : "com.mgtest.app.model.dao.Message" }
```